# Labels package outputting wrong number of columns

Tags: formatting, sticky-labels

I'm trying to output a somewhat heterogeneous page of business card-shaped items, containing a category label and some information about each category. I need three of each of the cards, with there being a total of ~30 different kinds of cards I need generated (so for a total of say 90 cards). I'm using the label package to accomplish this like so:

```
\documentclass[9pt,landscape, letterpaper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\LabelCols=5%
\LabelRows=2%
\LeftPageMargin=12.0mm%
\RightPageMargin=6.0mm%
\TopPageMargin=16.5mm%
\BottomPageMargin=16.5mm%
\InterLabelColumn=6mm%
\InterLabelRow=5.0mm%
\LeftLabelBorder=6mm%
\RightLabelBorder=3mm%
\TopLabelBorder=7mm%
\BottomLabelBorder=6mm%
\numberoflabels=3%
\LabelGridtrue%  <-- or \LabelGridfalse
\LabelInfotrue
%
\begin{document}
         \addresslabel[\fboxsep=4mm]{%
        {%

        {\Large\scshape Category Name}\\[1ex]

        \vspace{4ex}1: Person Li\\2: Person\\}
                            }


        \addresslabel[\fboxsep=4mm]{%
        {%

        {\Large\scshape Category Name}\\[1ex]

        \vspace{4ex}8: Person\\9: Person\\}
                            }

   \end{document}
```

Because of the way I've set this up, I'd like to have them be single-sided, with 5 columns by two columns of cards such that they can be cut from a single 8.5x11 page. However, this is a schematic of what I get instead:

```
card card card 
card card
card
```

While it's generating the correct amount of cards, all six should fit on a single page given that I've set `\labelcols` and `\labelrows`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the blank lines between the two `\addresslabel`. Otherwise, LaTeX will think you want to start a new paragraph after your first 3 labels. The "funny" part is that `labels` doesn't take the paragraph break into account, and does still end the row when the 5th label is displayed, that's why you're getting a third row.

Also, as a side-note:

- `article` has no `9pt` option;
- `landscape` works better with the `geometry` package (see [this blog post](https://texblog.org/2007/11/10/landscape-in-latex/) for further explanations).

This should do what you were expecting:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}

\LabelCols=5%
\LabelRows=2%
\LeftPageMargin=12.0mm%
\RightPageMargin=6.0mm%
\TopPageMargin=16.5mm%
\BottomPageMargin=16.5mm%
\InterLabelColumn=6mm%
\InterLabelRow=5.0mm%
\LeftLabelBorder=6mm%
\RightLabelBorder=3mm%
\TopLabelBorder=7mm%
\BottomLabelBorder=6mm%
\numberoflabels=3%
\LabelGridtrue%  <-- or \LabelGridfalse
\LabelInfotrue
%
\begin{document}
         \addresslabel[\fboxsep=4mm]{%
        {%

        {\Large\scshape Category Name}\\[1ex]

        \vspace{4ex}1: Person Li\\2: Person\\}
                            }
        \addresslabel[\fboxsep=4mm]{%
        {%

        {\Large\scshape Category Name}\\[1ex]

        \vspace{4ex}8: Person\\9: Person\\}
                            }

   \end{document}
```

Output:

[image: 5 labels then 1 label]

Comment: Sorry for the delay- this worked great, thanks so much!